# Lucene's MultiFieldQueryParser ignores setDefaultOperator

Tags: lucene, pylucene

I'm trying to change the default operator for a MultiFieldQueryParser:

```
fields = [...]
query = "hello stackoverflow"
clauses = [BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD, ...]

parser = MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, fields, analyzer)
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParserBase.AND_OPERATOR)
query = parser.parse(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, query, fields, clauses, analyzer)
```

The resulting query is:

```
(FieldA:hello FieldA:stackoverflow) (FieldB:hello FieldB:stackoverflow)
```

How can I get an AND query to retrieve only these documents that contain BOTH words (hello AND stackoverflow) in one or more of the available fields (fieldA, fieldB)?

Thanks! - PyLucene 4.8.0, Python 2.7 64 bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `MultiFieldQueryParser.parse` methods that take a bunch of arguments are all *static*.  The query parser instance and anything you did to it might as well not be there at all, what you have is equivalent to:

```python
query = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, query, fields, clauses, analyzer)
```

The `parse` you want, when using a instance of the query parser, is [the one that just takes a string](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/QueryParserBase.html#parse(java.lang.String)).

```python
fields = ["FieldA", "FieldB"]
query = "hello stackoverflow"

parser = MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_CURRENT, fields, analyzer)
parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParserBase.AND_OPERATOR)
query = parser.parse(query)
```

Comment: PyLucene's method binding seems to be broken, I got an error saying "descriptor parse requires a QueryParserBase object but received a str". When I call it like query = MultiFieldQueryParser.parse(parser, query), it works like a charme. Thank you!

Comment: The getMultiFieldQuery method on line 284 of MultiFieldQueryParser (lucene version 8.1.1) looks fishy. I had to switch the BooleanClause.Occur from SHOULD to MUST to get AND behavior.

Comment: same here, your way worked for me too, thank you @PeterClause

Answer (score 0):

```
searcher = IndexSearcher(reader)
analyzer = WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LATEST)
fields = ('a', 'b', 'c')
parser = MultiFieldQueryParser(fields, analyzer)
query = parser.parser(query)
results = searcher.search(query,10)
```